# Keras input shape, simple array of input lists

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

where each array([x1, x2, x3, ... , x15]) represents a single input

```
[array([0.        , 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333,
   0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.        , 0.08333333, 0.08333333,
   0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.        ])
 array([0.04166667, 0.10416667, 0.10416667, 0.08333333, 0.        ,
       0.10416667, 0.10416667, 0.02083333, 0.10416667, 0.08333333,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.125     , 0.125     , 0.        ])
 array([0.04166667, 0.        , 0.125     , 0.10416667, 0.02083333,
       0.125     , 0.125     , 0.02083333, 0.10416667, 0.        ,
       0.02083333, 0.02083333, 0.14583333, 0.14583333, 0.        ])
 ...
 array([0.4375    , 0.0625    , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.0625    , 0.        , 0.25      , 0.        , 0.08333333,
       0.04166667, 0.02083333, 0.        , 0.04166667, 1.        ])
 array([0.45833333, 0.        , 0.02083333, 0.02083333, 0.02083333,
       0.08333333, 0.        , 0.25      , 0.        , 0.08333333,
       0.04166667, 0.02083333, 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ])
 array([0.5       , 0.        , 0.        , 0.02083333, 0.02083333,
       0.        , 0.02083333, 0.27083333, 0.02083333, 0.10416667,
       0.0
       4166667, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ])]
```

going into a model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=15, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(14, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

complains:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (15,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How can I reshape the input data to fit this model?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't want a numpy array inside, it should be lists internally but an array at the topmost level only

```
X_train = np.array([x.tolist() for x in df['board_in'].values])
y_train = df['target']
y_train = np.array([y for y in df['target'].values])
```